# Помогите решить задачу с множественным наследованием на Java

Tags: java, android

Множественное наследование

Есть столы. У них много всяких полей, методов, внутренняя
 логика.

Есть шкафы. У них тоже много полей, методов, внутренняя логика.

И есть тумбочки, которые являются как столами, так и шкафами,
 а также содержат свою специфическую логику, поля, методы.

Написать ООП-модель в Java 6 (не 8), описывающую столы, шкафы
 и тумбочки. Пользователь, работающий с нашими классами, не должен ничего знать о хитрых способах, с помощью которых мы обходим ограничения языка. Для него это просто шкафы, столы и тумбочки. Созданную тумбочку можно записать как в переменную типа "Шкаф", так
 и в переменную типа "Стол".

Как я понял нужны интерфейсы. Но вот не получается решить до конца( Подайте хоть идею плиз

Comment: Расскажите в трех словах, как бы вы решали данную задачу. Очень поможете!

Comment: Ваш вопрос требует уточнений. А именно: 
1. Все эти предметы они часть интерьера? 
2. Эти предметы являются товаром?
3. Эти предметы производятся и являются предметом производства из каких либо материалов?
Если стол состоит у вас в том числе из тумбочки, то это не наследование.
И он "Стол" должен содержать в себе класс "Тумбочка"
А интерфейсы это глаголы - то что делает тумбочка, или то что делают с тумбочкой.

Мы не обходим хитрости языка, мы их используем.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тут надо знать особенности языка Java, чтобы понять, что интерфейсы действительно нужны для решения данной задачи.
Так как один класс может одновременно реализовать несколько интерфейсов.
Но, при этом, один класс может наследоваться ТОЛЬКО от одного класса-родителя.

Видится такое решение:

```
interface Desk; //Стол
//реализация интерфейса Desk
class DeskImpl implements Desk;

interface Cupboard; //Шкаф
//реализация интерфейса Cupboard
class CupboardImpl implements Cupboard;

//класс тумбочка, реализующий интерфейсы Стола и Шкафа
class Nightstand implements Desk, Cupboard;
```

Решение не единственное, но детальнее расписать его сложно, так как задача не детально описана. В частности непонятно что должны уметь делать Стол, Шкаф и Тумбочка. Если будет понимание, то возможно потребуется ввести абстрактные классы для оптимизации.

Минус решения в том, что для тумбочки придется заново реализовывать методы от Стола и Шкафа. Но повторюсь, что данную проблему можно решить через абстрактные классы.

Comment: Стол, Шкаф и Тумбочка не обязательно должны уметь что-то делать. Например считать сами себя. Интерфейс бывает нужен чтобы произвести действия над этими предметами. Пример интерфейс Товар, интерфейс Компоновка(Интерьерный дизайн), интерфейс Сконструировать из. Логично наследовать их от Мебель и интерфейсы реализовывать от Товар, Компоновка(Перестановка). Как-то так. Нарисуйте простые связи на листочке и вы поймете как нужно будет спроектировать архитектуру. Промер: Что делают над этим предметом или что делает этот предмет. Из чего он состоит. Простые связи дадут вам понимание.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы избежать дублирования кода поведение тумбочки и шкафа можете вынести в отдельные классы и внедрять в столы, шкафы и тумбочки их переменные. Определите интерфейсы стола и шкафа и реализуя их делегируйте их работу методам соответствующих классов поведения. Соответственно у классов поведения будут свои интерфейсы поведения стола и шкафа. У тумбочки будет внутри два поля с поведением шкафа и стола.

```
//интерфейс стол
public interface Table {
    void someTableMethod();
}

//интерфейс шкаф
public interface Cupboard {
    void someCupboardMethod();
}

//интерфейс тумбочка
public interface Nightstand extends Table, Cupboard {}

//интерфейс поведение стола (методы свойственные столу)
public interface TableBehavior {
    void someMethod();
}

//интерфейс поведение шкафа (методы свойственные шкафу)
public interface CupboardBehavior {
    void someMethod();
}

//какой-то стол
public class SomeTable implements Table {
    TableBehavior tableBehavior;

    public SomeTable(TableBehavior tableBehavior) {
        this.tableBehavior = tableBehavior;
    }

    @Override
    public void someTableMethod() {
        tableBehavior.someMethod();
    }
}

//какой-то шкаф
public class SomeCupboard implements Cupboard {
    CupboardBehavior cupboardBehavior;

    public SomeCupboard(CupboardBehavior cupboardBehavior) {
        this.cupboardBehavior = cupboardBehavior;
    }

    @Override
    public void someCupboardMethod() {
        cupboardBehavior.someMethod();
    }
}

//какая-то тумбочка
public class SomeNightstand implements Nightstand {
    CupboardBehavior cupboardBehavior;
    TableBehavior tableBehavior;

    public SomeNightstand(CupboardBehavior cupboardBehavior, TableBehavior tableBehavior) {
        this.cupboardBehavior = cupboardBehavior;
        this.tableBehavior = tableBehavior;
    }

    @Override
    public void someTableMethod() {
        tableBehavior.someMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public void someCupboardMethod() {
        cupboardBehavior.someMethod();
    }
}

//реализация свойств какого-то стола
public class SomeTableBehavior implements TableBehavior {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        //do smth
    }
}

//реализация свойств какого-то шкафа
public class SomeCupboardBehavior implements CupboardBehavior {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        //do smth
    }
}
```

теперь при изменении свойств стола не придётся переписывать тумбочку. И можно создавать самые разные тумбочки на основе одного класса, к примеру есть столы с тремя ногами, четырьмя ногами, n-ногами. Теперь чтобы реализовать тумбу с тремя или четырьмя ногами не надо писать две отдельные реализации, а просто при создании в конструктор подать нужные реализации.